# Social Media Portfolios

Tags: communication, portfolio

I'm just starting to come round to the idea of using social media, and as I'm not a big fan, I want to use as few profiles as possible, on my prefered platform which is **Twitter**.

My main area of work is very music orientated: rock and metal, fashion, events, tattoos, alternative models, autos, etc, but I also want to explore the darker side of the culture, which has more to do with alternative models doing fetish work.

So the problem here is that I could almost split this into 3 parts:

1. Regular Content - Music, Fahion, Motors, Models
2. NSFW Content - Adult/Fetish, which relates directly to Regular Content
3. NSFW+ Content - Adult/Fetish, But more sexually explicit

I was thinking of having 2 accounts per subject ( "personal/communications" and "portfolio/promotional" )

A good way of seeting this out would be to have:

- @MyName
- @MyName_NSFW
- @MyName_XXX

and

- @MyPortfolio
- @MyPortfolio_NSFW
- @MyPortfolio_XXX

In theory, allowing people visiting the NSFW and XXX accounts to realise that it's an extension to a regular account.

The problem of course is that as soon as people follow me on "@MyPortfolio", social networks are quick to tell them that a similar account exists - "@MyPortfolio_NSFW", which I don't really want.

So should I instead have 3 completely different names as a business, to deal with clients from each area of work?

Answer (score 1):

Preface: I'm *not* a big social media user... so keep that in mind as you read. I find social media, in general, a waste of time and think it's only *really* useful as a marketing/advertising tool if you *already* have a following of some sort, such as being a celebrity or an existing, *established*, client base that is significant. But, that's all just my *opinion*. My clients, don't give a hoot what I'm doing on a daily basis, they just want their work as fast as I can turn it around. None of my client would be interested in a daily feed of my activities or thoughts. They simply wouldn't care. But those are my clients. Your audience may differ.

---

What I've found, in general, is that a *focused* business does **much better** than a diversified business when the operating staff is limited. If you have 3 people you can assign to manage 3 social media accounts, then by all means that may be good for you. As a single individual spreading yourself across multiple accounts merely means no single account will get the attention it needs. If you aren't already a dedicated social media enthusiast then spending so much time managing accounts, for me, would become drudgery and I'd quickly grow to dislike the effort and then things would languish. That will do far more harm than if the account was never created in the first place.

As a sole proprietary, single member business, I find it is **often** best to focus attention into a primary area of desired work. This allows for *much* more dedicated advertising and targeting. Most freelancers, after a period of initial client acquisition, start to fall into a "niché" or area of specialty. It's rare that you find a freelancer working on absolutely anything and everything. Sure many *can* explore some broader areas based upon client requests. However, it's best to focus on where you *want* to work, not on what you *can* work on.

A common mistake, I feel, that those starting out make is trying to be everything to everyone. This may make for more work, but not necessarily *better* work or *better* clients. You may find you can fill your days with client requests, but they are often one-off, barely profitable, tasks which take so much time you are left struggling to find better paying work. And the smaller clients tend to not really be repeat customers. For me, the bread and butter of freelancing is the *repeat* business. It typically eliminates the need to do any broad advertising and *often* the need for *any* advertising.

My advice would be do **one thing well**. When that has a "life of its own" and is not something which needs constant attention, *then* start thinking about broadening the scope. If you excel at one thing, word-of-mouth will often be a catalyst for more work in that area and the need to advertise those skills diminishes. This frees you to start looking at advertising another area and attempt to grow *that* into a larger revenue stream.

In addition, *clients* will dictate where you may want to focus. It could easily be that no one you find is interested in the more NSFW content, so why bother advertising it? Or you could discover that *most* of the clients you come across ask about NSW type of content.. so dedicating some advertising there may be beneficial. You shouldn't assume that because you *can* do something there's an adequate market for you in that area. If you are starting out, leave the more risqué stuff for later, unless that's all you really want to do.

---

Again, this is all merely my *opinion* based upon my experience as a freelancer over a couple of decades.

Comment: Thanks Scott. It's not so much that I *Want to do* more risque stuff, more a case of it being related to my overall goal - Doing work for bands and festivals who use glamour/fetish models in their marketing. The way I see it, these girls could potentially be a great future client, so I don't see why I shouldn't connect with them, all be it on a NSFW version of my accounts. I guess primarily I'd like to use my account as a micro-lifestyle-blog, picking up clients and advertising what I've done for others. It may be that I need a dedicated account for people who are just interesed in projects.

Comment: Markets may simply vary. My experience has been that any individual who sees my work and wants me to do something, while pleasant, doesn't provide a *sustainable* business model in most instances. Sometimes it can if they own a company, but as a single person, often not. I don't target "models" hoping they'll want my work - I'll certainly work for them if approached though. I target the *agency* the model works for which results in *much,* more work than a single individual. And the agency isn't necessarily interested in my "lifestyle" they are interested in my work and professionalism.

Comment: The problem I see is that a lot of people I want to work with are independent and are not represented by an agency or a label. That's the point of me wanting to work with them - And I feel that having too many individual accounts would limit the posts I make getting out to the broader audience. I guess it comes down to the fact that I know it's possible to work in this way ( as many lifestyle bloggers / influencers are doing ), I just don't know the best way to configure my social networks in order to do it as effectively as possible.

Comment: "Lifestyle bloggers and influencers" are *not* trying to get anyone to hire them for some specific ability. They seek someone to pay them for what they would be doing anyway with or without compensation. It's a completely different market as I see it.

Comment: Yeah maybe `freelancing` isn't the best stack to ask this on, but it seems logical as its about showcasing work that has been done. Long story short, I know I can run social networks, I have a good business idea in there and a website to showcase my work on - I just have no idea how to get the ball rolling

Comment: A chef and a food critic can't market themselves the same. Kind of sounds like you're a "chef" but want to use marketing models of "food critics". Good luck with it. I simply feel you may be inadvertently targeting a market that may not be the best for business prospects.

Comment: Actually it's more the other way round - I used to own a music magazine, but had a lot of call from tattoo artists and writers who wanted to be featured. I realised that my potential for who I could feature was bigger. Now, I want to do more serious ( written and photographic ) work, but to also keep a presence online to make sure people know of my existence. If that makes sense.